# Connection did receive data returns null and crashes the application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, ipad

I make a call to the server on a button click and the connection `didReceiveData` returns a `Null` and crashes the application. But having an `if`-`else` condition to check if data is `Null`, with initiate the server call again in `if` condition a best practice to do this?

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [storeRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [storeRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [storeRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [storeRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection;

    theConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:storeRequest delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1
{
    if (data1==nil)
    {
        [self downloadDetails];//Restart the download
    }
    else
    {
        receivedData =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

        [receivedData appendData:data1];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSError* error;
NSMutableArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                             options:kNilOptions
                             error:&error];

[appDelegate.inboxArray addObjectsFromArray:jsonArray];

}
```

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code that sets up your connection and also the code of your delegate methods?

Comment: @ROY Have you implemented [`didFailWithError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:)? I'd do so, and look at the `NSError` object. Let us know what it says. Also, can you `NSLog` the `postLength` and `postData` prior to initiating the request to make sure they're both valid?

Comment: Also, please show the method `downloadDetails`... perhaps it is doing some setup step which this method is not...

Comment: @Rob This is the complete code what i have been using, I have rectified my mistake by creating the NSMutableData when i set up my NSURLConnection.Also have implemented the code for didFailWithError.The problem arises only when i use a 2G-Edge connection.Presently i am working on Wi-Fi and on a simulator and the crash never happens , i will have my device back in 3 days,and will post u didFailWithError.Also the postData and postLength are valid as i receive a 200 response in didReceiveResponse (upon using wifi).

Comment: @Rob i got the error code as -1003 and localized description as "A server with the specified hostname could not be found"

Comment: @ROY It's hard to say without seeing the URL. Two candidates, tho: 1. Is the hostname you're using on your private network (e.g. an IP number of a server on your subnet)? Is the hostname available from the Internet? 2. Does your device, when it's on an Edge network, have connectivity to the Internet? You might want to use the classes within the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample to confirm connectivity before trying to retrieve data. That way, you can gracefully defer network operations until the server is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

receivedData needs to be an instance variable so that it has storage duration that persists between calls to the delegate methods. A common pattern is to use lazy instantiation in it's getter (make it a "private" `@property`).

The way you have it now, if you get more than one chunk, you are wiping out previous chunks (and not actually letting anything else access your data).

I can only assume you are implementing the other delegate methods as appropriate...

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you and rob .Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I am getting the error code as -1003 .Any suggestions now what can be done ?

Comment: Check out this page, which indicates an unknown host: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Comment: can you suggest a way how to overcome this in the app ie ..should i make the server call again after having a delay ? whenever the host is not found ?

Comment: Usually that means there is not a reliable DNS response. Do you get different responses on your simulator vs. device? Best thing to do depends a LOT on your context and desired UX. Perhaps best to prompt the user and allow them to manually 'retry' or cancel their efforts; canceling should take them "back" in their workflow. This way you don't get into a potential infinite loop if the DNS is actually never going to respond with a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question as to whether you should immediately reinitiate the request upon failure is a good practice, the answer is no. If you do want to retry, you should:

- only do so if another request has a reasonable chance of success (e.g. it didn't fail for complete lack of network connectivity; you'd only retry once your implementation of the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class tells you that the network connection is reestablished);
- employ "maximum number of retries" logic to make sure you limit the retries to some reasonable number (e.g. you don't want to use up the user's data plan, concern for device performance, UX, etc.);
- put in some delay before retrying (for example, if your server is not responding because it's overwhelmed by requests, battering it with an incessant stream of requests won't help); and
- if the connection has failed and the user returns the app to foreground, start that process over (e.g. a common scenario is "oh, I forgot to turn off airplane mode", go to settings, turn it off, and return the app, at which point, it should automatically retry if it hadn't yet succeeded or if it certain amount of time has passed (e.g. 24 hours).

In terms of the detail of your particular problem, you should show us what [`didFailWithError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection%3adidFailWithError%3a) reports. And if you're still having problems, I'd also suggest inspecting `postData` and `postLength` prior to the request and sure they have valid values.

By the way, ctrahey is right that you have a problem in your `didReceiveData`. The process is generally:

- create a `NSMutableData` when you first create the `NSURLConnection` (or in [`didReceiveResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveResponse%3a));
- append data to it in [`didReceiveData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveData%3a), but do nothing with this data (unless you're doing some streaming-based operation, which you are not);
- evaluate and act upon the results in [`connectionDidFinishLoading`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connectionDidFinishLoading%3a); and
- make sure you implement `didFailWithError` as discussed above.

Comment: This is the complete code what i have been using, I have rectified my mistake by creating the NSMutableData when i set up my NSURLConnection.Also have implemented the code for didFailWithError.The problem arises only when i use a 2G-Edge connection.Presently i am working on Wi-Fi and on a simulator and the crash never happens , i will have my device back in 3 days,and will post u didFailWithError.Also the postData and postLength are valid as i receive a 200 response in didReceiveResponse (upon using wifi).

Comment: @ROY Very good. I'll keep an eye out for that. Good luck. Sadly, it's tough for us to diagnose just by looking at the code, but hopefully we can figure out what's going on.